# Hopcroft und Karp Algorithm and a suitable representation for a graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, matching

Hey Guys I have a small question about the Hopcroft and Karp Algorithm.

I have a task to solve where I have to calculate the perfect matching. My professor told me I should use the Hopcroft Algorithm. With that I can calculate the maximal matching and then valited with (number of edges/2 = number of matching) if there is a perfect matching

Some background: Currently the Graphs will be representated as followed.

---

|(0,0) (1,0) (2,0) (3,0) (4,0) (5,0)|

|(0,1) (1,1) ***(2,1) (3,1) (4,1)*** (5,1)|

|(0,2) ***(1,2) (2,2)*** (3,2) (4,2) ***(5,2)***|

|(0,3) (1,3) (2,3) ***(3,3) (4,3) (5,3)***|

---

The 2-Tupel representing node coordinates in a room and the big one are actual nodes for this example

We dont count the diagonal ones as neighbors, so (2,1) has just (3,1) and (2,2) as neighbors

Also this example has 2 Graphs (it could be more or less, the points are random) but its cleary not bipartite.

Now is the problem I dont know how to apply this algorithm. Actually I know that if you just consider the diagonal values of a graph you could form a bipartite graph.

Lets say Graph 1. is with the points (1,2) (2,1) (3,1) (4,1), the graph could be bipartite if we imgagine that each diagonal is a subset of the Graph.

For example the bipartite parts are for Graph 1. { (1,2) (2,1)}, { (3,1), (2,2)} and {(4,1}) but I dont know if this helps me, I just think it makes it harder to programm.

So the question is how could I use the Hopcraft Algorithm for a single graph which is representated as above(lets say for Graph 1)

Comment: If the problem is you don't know how to apply the algorithm, then maybe that's exactly why you were given this exercise - to prod you to learn how!  If you understand the algorithm, you should be able to write pseudocode for it.  If you can write pseudocode, you should be able to execute it by hand.  If you can't write pseudocode, there must be something specific you don't understand; ask about that.

Comment: As it stands all we have to go with is that you don't understand the algorithm, but you don't say why or what you do understand, and you don't articulate a specific question.  That makes it hard for us to give a useful answer.  This is a question-and-answer site, so you need to articulate a specific question.  We're not going to do your exercise for you, or explain the entire Hopcraft algorithm to you (there are plenty of resources that already have such an explanation), but if you have a specific question about the algorithm, we might be able to answer it.

Comment: I now what you mean, but I asking myself and you guys, if its even possible to use the algorithm with Graphes above? Thats why I am unsure. I wont deep into the algo if its not even possible. I hope you understand what i mean :D

Edit: I never said that you should explain me the algorithm or do my exercise. The only question is if I can transform a graph like this into a bipartite graph, or even are graphs which the spezification from above in generell in a way bipartite

Comment: This is your exercise, so it is for you to figure out.  As [Wikipedia explains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm), the Hopcroft-Karp algorithm can be used with any bipartite graph.  Do you have a bipartite graph?  If yes, what can you conclude?  It sounds like you should spend more time studying how the algorithm works.

Comment: I am not sure if you understand me right, as I said I have Graphs like above and I am not sure if they are Bipartite or not with spezification like( just neighbors are edges etc.)

Comment: Are you asking "How do I tell whether a graph is bipartite?"  If so, then you should study about bipartite graphs.  Look at what the definition is, and try applying it.  I'm having a very hard time understanding what your question is.  This site is not intended for interactive back-and-forth conversations, so your post needs to be very clear about what your question is, before we can answer it.

Comment: Ok I see, I know there are algorithm to test if Graphs are bipartite or not. I know there is Hopcraft to calculate the maximal matching. What I dont understand is, my proof says with Graphs like above we can use the Hopcraft algorithm but I dont understand why. Because the graph above is not bipartite(?)

Comment: So your question is, how do I apply the Hopcroft algorithm to a graph that is not bipartite?  You can't.  You need [a different algorithm for that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#In_general_graphs.)  Perhaps you should ask your professor this question.  Also, if that is your question, please edit your post to make it clear that this is what you are asking.  I don't understand what graph you are trying to show us above; I don't understand what the "|(0,0) (1,0) ..." notation means.

Comment: These should be coordinates with possible nodes, and the big ones are the actual vertices. I think if you see it like this, you can better understand why parts of graphs like this (without diagonal neighbors) can be viewed as bipartite parts